# Unexpected error - regression model using glm

Tags: r, regression, glm, mlogit, unexpected-token

I am trying to do a regression using glm but it is coming with an unexpected error
Here is the code:

```
mod1 <- glm(N_agreements ~ Population + PublicStaff + Macrorregion + Direct Plan, data = ILC, family = binomial)
summary(mod1)
```

the message:

```
Error: unexpected symbol in "mod1 <- glm(Education ~ Population + PublicStaff + Macrorregion + Direct Plan"
```

Comment: Use ```mod1 <- glm(N_agreements ~ Population + PublicStaff + Macrorregion + `Direct Plan`, data = ILC, family = binomial)``` You need backticks around column names with spaces. It's usually better not to have column names with spaces.

Comment: On @MrFlick's note, when I have data that really *needs* to have a space in the column in some report, I change the name to include the space *just before rendering* the report. This is a form of "just-in-time" data naming/formatting.